# disableing enter/return key from within Tiny MCE

Tags: javascript

Hi I've tried a numerous amounts of "googled" snippets for disabling enter / return key but nothing is working. Any ideas on how to disable the enter / return key whilst in tinyMCE textarea?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code I used to disable the enter key on certain inline elements. It works with TinyMCE 4:

```
tinymce.init({
    tinymce_jquery: true,
    selector: ".className",
    inline: true,
    toolbar: "undo redo",
    menubar: false,
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.on('keydown', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: An anonymous user suggested also calling `tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor.getElement().blur();` to unfocus the input when enter is pressed. Feel free use that if desired. I haven't tested it. I felt it didn't belong in an edit to the original answer but might be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Hai Phil,

```
ed.onKeyPress.addToTop(function(ed, e) {
if ((e.charCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)) {
    ed.setContent("");
    return tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(e);
}});
```

Or refer this [Disable enter key on tiny mce editor](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=10677)

Comment: Do you know where abouts to put it as I cant seem to get it to work?